# cv2.imread alters the base64 string from images and generates different results between OSes

Tags: python, opencv, base64, cross-platform

I am using OpenCV in Python on MacOS and Linux Ubuntu systems. My OpenCV version is 3.4.1.15.

I have tried three different methods of generating base64 strings for images, on two OS systems respectively:

1. Using plain Python:

   ```
   from base64 import b64encode
   with open("image_file.jpg", "rb") as file:
       base64string = b64encode(file.read()).decode("UTF-8")
   ```
2. Using `cv2.imread`:

   ```
   import cv2
   from base64 import b64encode
   cvbase64string = b64encode(cv2.imencode('.jpg', cv2.imread(image_file.jpg))[1]).decode("UTF-8")
   ```
3. Using plain Python after using `cv2.imwrite` for what `cv2.imread` gets:

   ```
   import cv2
   from base64 import b64encode
   cv2.imwrite("ioimage_file.jpg", cv2.imread("image_file.jpg"))
   with open("ioimage_file.jpg", "rb") as file:
       iobase64string = b64encode(file.read()).decode("UTF-8")
   ```

With my human eyes, I can't distinguish "ioimage_file.jpg" from "image_file.jpg". However, the base64 strings change.

1. On the same OS (either MacOS or Linux), `base64string` != `cvbase64string` == `iobase64string`.
2. Across OSes, `MAC_base64string` == `LINUX_base64string`, but `MAC_cvbase64string` != `LINUX_cvbase64string` and `MAC_iobase64string` != `LINUX_iobase64string`.

Why is that? Is there any way to solve it? Or is it a bug needed reporting?

This troubles me because I am developing OCR algorithm on different platforms, but different base64 strings yield different recognized characters from Google Vision API, which means I can't even reproduce my OCR results from one same image.

Comment: Why couldn't you just use `base64string` as they are stable?

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#Mat%20imread(const%20String&%20filename,%20int%20flags)

Comment: `imread` has different implementations on different platforms.

Comment: @Sraw because I need `cv2.resize`, `cv2.minAreaRect`, `cv2.getRotationMatrix2D`, etc. to preprocess the image before sending it out for recognition.